# Dmcli issue in powershell script

Tags: git, powershell-2.0, serena

I am writing one PowerShell script which is reading a CSV file and in that
script I am passing **Dimension commands** . One command is for connecting to  serena dimensions and another is for fetching files from dimensions.

```
dmcli FI $Specification /USER_FILENAME=$FilePath
```

Here

- `$specification` is a value from the CSV file
- `$filepath` is the path to store the downloaded file

The above code is to fetch code from dimensions and copy into the folder.

The code is working fine but failed for filenames and specification having space.

Answer (score 0):

Put the arguments in double quotes:

```
dmcli FI "$Specification" "/USER_FILENAME=$FilePath"
```

or like this:

```
dmcli FI "$Specification" /USER_FILENAME="$FilePath"
```

If that doesn't work try running the command in CMD with environment variables:

```
$env:Specification = $Specification
$env:FilePath      = $FilePath

& cmd /c 'dmcli FI "%Specification%" /USER_FILENAME="%FilePath%"'
```

Comment: Please provide an apt solution

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. But, there is still an issue regarding dimensions command.

Comment: Sure. Just let me get my crystal ball, so I can scry what that issue might be ...